# Type alias 'Permission' circularly references itself

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

I am defining a type for my Permissions object which is:

```
const Permissions = {
    PageManagement: {
        MainPageManagement: {
            ViewPage: 'view-page',
            CreatePage: 'create-page',
            UpdatePage: 'update-page',
            DeletePage: 'delete-page',
            ActivateDeactivatePage: 'activate-deactivate-page',
        },
        PageSectionManagement: {
            ViewPageSection: 'view-page-section',
            CreatePageSection: 'create-page-section',
            UpdatePageSection: 'update-page-section',
            DeletePageSection: 'delete-page-section',
            ActivateDeactivatePageSection: 'activate-deactivate-page-section',
        },
    },
    RoleManagement: {
        ViewRole: 'view-role',
        CreateRole: 'create-role',
        UpdateRole: 'update-role',
        DeleteRole: 'delete-role',
        AssignRole: 'assign-role',
        RemoveRole: 'remove-role',
        ActivateDeactivateRole: 'activate-deactivate-role',
    },
};
```

As you can see, `PageManagement` has nested two objects, while `RoleManagement` doesn't have.
I'm trying to create a `n-level` nested type definition, the one that I've created now is:

```
type Permission = Record<string, string | Permission>
```

But it gives this error:

`Type alias 'Permission' circularly references itself`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm using `TypeScript v4.2.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Record` is the source of the problem. It requires a complete type before it can result in a type.

```
type Permission = { [key: string]: string | Permission }
```

This will work.

Comment: Thanks, the Object type is not generic, so after a little bit study of the typescript Utility Types docs, I thought the Record will be suitable. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use an interface instead of type.

```
const permissions: Permission = {
    PageManagement: {
        MainPageManagement: {
            ViewPage: 'view-page',
            CreatePage: 'create-page',
            UpdatePage: 'update-page',
            DeletePage: 'delete-page',
            ActivateDeactivatePage: 'activate-deactivate-page',
        },
        PageSectionManagement: {
            ViewPageSection: 'view-page-section',
            CreatePageSection: 'create-page-section',
            UpdatePageSection: 'update-page-section',
            DeletePageSection: 'delete-page-section',
            ActivateDeactivatePageSection: 'activate-deactivate-page-section',
        },
    },
    RoleManagement: {
        ViewRole: 'view-role',
        CreateRole: 'create-role',
        UpdateRole: 'update-role',
        DeleteRole: 'delete-role',
        AssignRole: 'assign-role',
        RemoveRole: 'remove-role',
        ActivateDeactivateRole: 'activate-deactivate-role',
    },
};

interface Permission {
  [key: string]: string | Permission
}
```

Also [reproduction example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4FsCWEJvBAXDABWXU2zBgF4YBvAWACgYnCBDAcwQFkWx2EUEYKPjqNm47mjAE%203XhwFCRDcauYA1NAgDuMjvgDkANy3aAtHD4GANCrWqAwkgQsoCPQkPBnrhBau2YvbMAKpwACa%20HoYArhG%20-hw2dsFMACIIADYIbtEwBuFZOX6WSYGpzACCwFBoRr4ZLDV1UXyGTbX1bmaFHS3dpQjJQaoAvuX2HgDKCM3gcnyKwjQpqZo607O14IYmOol%20EFtkwxVMTi65fDNzYF4%20A3xmR7enZ2GRVxw323f5cZ8Sk8Xr83hUMtkvggfmRDIVIUCOM9juAwalqp0Gi5ml13NcUX8DH1cT1sZjHkiQScJmpxqs6SMAEogbILBSCZaiYLrbTM7K7UxmJAsoY0xwPBB8zz5byXPzC7Jo8QfXxS2LxboK0WrcQQ4pq-Lw4pCkVKqqkNhgA1Ei1gE2KsXiRn8EBGSUiwzOFCu%20Wmx1VHFY4mqj35YPdXqBzV%20%20mBUYAbgYDCkbiQADMmghCMQMFhwCsxABtADWCAAnvhoEgpGwALqVqDVsBsGAAH2zqFzZAYoyAA)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was looking for the solution without interface. But your solution works too. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: sure, thank you too. But I recommend the usage of interfaces instead of types,  https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c little bit about differences.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I'll check that out